# Boot timeout when deploying Spring Boot application with JPA to Heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-rds

I have a Spring Boot 1.5.1 application that I'm deploying with heroku-maven-plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <appName>${heroku.appName}</appName>
    <includeTarget>false</includeTarget>
    <includes>
        <include>${basedir}/${heroku.fullArtifactName}</include>
    </includes>
    <processTypes>
        <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar ${heroku.fullArtifactName}</web>
    </processTypes>
</configuration>
```

I can see Heroku filling in the port from logs:

```
2018-03-18T18:16:25.966746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=42658 -jar target/be-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Initializing the application concludes with an error like seen in the following logs:

```
2018-03-18 18:18:26.046 DEBUG 4 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://app/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 18:18:26.048 DEBUG 4 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@72ea2f77
2018-03-18T18:19:32.196190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
```

Things work in my local environment (running through Intellij IDEA), logs for contrast:

```
2018-03-18 20:31:10.284 DEBUG --- o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2018-03-18 20:31:10.289 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:10.290 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:11.900 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:11.900 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:13.257 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:13.257 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:14.633 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:14.634 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:15.991 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:15.991 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:17.344 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:17.345 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:18.692 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:18.693 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:20.068 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:20.069 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:21.388 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:21.388 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:22.751 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection    : Instantiating driver using class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [url=jdbc:mysql://url/db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false]
2018-03-18 20:31:22.752 DEBUG --- o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil     : Attempting to load class[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc
2018-03-18 20:31:24.113 DEBUG --- o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2018-03-18 20:31:24.168  INFO --- j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-03-18 20:31:24.179 DEBUG --- o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : PersistenceUnitInfo [
```

It does take some time to get the JDBC connection locally aswell with quite a few attempts to load the driver class, but the connection works fine.

The configuration doesn't seem to differ really in local and Heroku and my debugging efforts haven't yielded much. Perhaps someone has an idea where should I direct my attention?

EDIT:
I'm using Amazon RDS for the DB and I'm thinking this might be an access issue (not sure why I can access the DB locally though...). Will check soon if that is the case.

Comment: Are you running the app locally with the same `java -jar` command?

Comment: No, usually I run it from a Spring Boot run configuration in Intellij Idea, but I did try running it with the command in a terminal and it started fine (similar multiple attempts to load class, but connection with DB works fine). Server startup time:

`2018-03-18 23:45:22.473  INFO 22838 --- [           main] com.digitund.ApplicationMain             : Started ApplicationMain in 21.863 seconds (JVM running for 22.46)`

Comment: Are you connecting to a local db? Have you tried connecting to the Heroku DB from your local system?

Comment: Edited my post to say that I'm using Amazon RDS. Could connect to it with a local instance of my application and with my IDE, but failed on Heroku. I'll see what I can configure on Amazon side (not much experience there which threw me off the scent due to me being able to connect locally).

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the postgresql JDBC driver.

Comment: Make sure you have correct accesibility rules in your amazon rds security. It looks to me that heroku IPs can not access to those instances.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue, thanks! Will go by the guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds at some point. At the time being I made use of Elastic Beanstalk instead of Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You have a port issue, you are not bindding to the port Heroku expects you to, ry to get hold of the `$PORT` value in your Procfile, and configure it to be your -Dserver.port

Add this tou your `web:` line in your `Procfile`:

```
-Dserver.port=$PORT
```

Comment: I do pass the port via heroku-maven-plugin:

    <processTypes>
    <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar ${heroku.fullArtifactName}</web>
    </processTypes>

And I can see Heroku picking it up:

    2018-03-18T17:46:27.782513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=32847 -jar target/be-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: This formatting thing really got me, sorry, just couldn't get it right.

But I think you can decipher the relevant `pom.xml` config and heroku log entry and seems that the server port is okay.

Comment: ok, so I don't know what is happening. maybe add this to your question

Comment: I would run the command locally via a Java jar command then run `heroku bash` and try to run the same command. I suspect that you don't have the RDS security group configured to let heroku access RDS.